# Where are Python wheels created ?

Tags: python

I do this

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python c:\\python34\kissdownloader\setup.py bdist_wheel
```

and I get this after some other stuff

```
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\kissdownloader-1.dist-info\WHEEL
```

I goto my python root and there's nothing there , no build folder or anything . Is the thing somewhere else ? Oh and I don't have a manifest.in file if that makes any difference .

My setup.py file looks like this :

```
from setuptools import setup 
   setup ( 
        name='kissdownloader',
        version='1',
        description = 'A kisscartoon/kissanime downloader' ,
        package_dir={'kissdownloader':'C:\\Python34'},
        author='Vriska',
        author_email='xyz@gmail.com',
        install_requires = ['bs4','cfscrape','requests'],
        package_data={'data' : ['C:\Program Files\PhantomJS\phantomjs.exe']},
    )
```

Comment: Have you looked at `build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\kissdownloader-1.dist-info\WHEEL` **relative to the current working directory**?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, you mean where setup.py is placed? Yeah nothing there

Comment: No, the current working directory, according to your paste, is `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, so I'd expect there to be new `build` and `dist` subdirectories there.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, oh so I'll have to CD my way to the setup.py. Thanks I'll try that

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, thank you that certainly was what happened. If you post this as the answer I'll select it in case someone silly runs into this. Also if you don't mind, I doubt my package data got uploaded to pip, am I doing it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is generated in your *current working directory*. In your case, that's `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, because that's where you started Python. You'll find a `build` and `dist` directory; the latter contains the completed wheel.

If you want the directories to be created next to `setup.py`, change your directory to `c:\python34\kissdownloader\` first. Many a Python project expects you to run `setup.py` there anyway.

As a side note: I wouldn't bundle the PhantomJS binary in with your project. Instead, require users to install it separately; they may already have it installed anyway, and you may run into legal issues by re-distributing it in your own project without at least a compatible license.